# How can I count my table row and display to my highcharts

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

Can you guys help me with my problem?
My Highcharts graph working , But I don't have any idea to count my table cell in  $as_name with month $created_date and display only gel data to my highcharts like categorie (month) and data to(as_name)count,
this is my database and my code,

Any help is well appreciated Thank you..

**database**

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `as_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4


|AS_name|creater_date|
---------------------
|gel    |2020-12-21  |
|gel    |2020-12-21  |
|jhon   |2020-12-21  |
|gel    |2020-12-21  |
|jhon   |2020-12-21  |
---------------------
```

**controller**.

```
public function index() 
{      
    $data['list'] = $this->data();
    $this->load->view('dashboard');
    
}
public function data()
{
    $data = $this->Dashboard_model->get_data();
            
    $category = array();
    $category['name'] = 'Month';
            
    $series1 = array();
    $series1['name'] = 'WordPress';
            
    $series2 = array();
    $series2['name'] = 'Code Igniter';
            
    $series3 = array();
    $series3['name'] = 'Highcharts';
            
    foreach ($data as $row) {
                
        $category['data'][] = $row->month;
        $series1['data'][]  = $row->wordpress;
        $series2['data'][]  = $row->codeigniter;
        $series3['data'][]  = $row->highchart;
    }
            
             
    $result = array();
    array_push($result,$category);
    array_push($result,$series1);
    array_push($result,$series2);
    array_push($result,$series3);
            
    print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

**model**

```
 public function get_data()
    {
        $this->db->select('month,wordpress,codeigniter,highchart');
        $this->db->from('sample');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var options = {
                    colors: ['#058DC7', '#800080', '#F08080'],//line
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'model',
                        type: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 100
                    },
                    
                    title: {
                        text: 'Month',//title here
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
      
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: []
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'click'//side commment
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b>'+
                                this.x +': '+ this.y;
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 40,
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
    
                    series: []
                }
    var url = <your web url> + "data1.json"; // assumes that your URL ends with a forward slash
                $.getJSON("url", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                    options.series[0] = json[1];
                    options.series[1] = json[2];
                    options.series[2] = json[3];
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            });
    
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    
    </head>



**body**
 <div class="jumbotron" >
                                  

<div id="model" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;" ></div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Hi @J HON, Your chart options seem to be fine, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f1zog82L/ Could you provide me with a sample of your json?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJcy2.png is this what you mean? Json output

Comment: Yes, thanks. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hmjxfcsa/ is that what you want to achieve?